# Frontend sorting

Tags: pagination, front-end, sort

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Which partly works already, I can sort with 2 dropdowns and have a pagination.

I have to merge both dropdowns into one, and add "posts per page" without screwing up the pagination.

Currently I'm using [WP-PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for the pagination

### Current code:

```
<?php
$orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
$order = $_GET['order'];
?>


<form action="" method="get">
    <select name="order" id="order">
        <option value="asc" <?php if ($order == "asc"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> >ASC</option>
        <option value="desc" <?php if ($order == "desc"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> >DESC</option>
    </select>
    <select name="orderby" id="sorting">
        <option value="title" <?php if ($orderby == "title"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> >Title</option>
        <option value="date" <?php if ($orderby == "date"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?> >Date</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){wp_pagenavi();} ?>
```